# React Router 6 useNavigate is not finding the correct right away which returns "page not found" right before the correct route is found

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Pretty much exactly as the title says. I have an app where you must login before viewing any pages and after the login the route goes to my page not found route and then routes correctly a second later. Before I implemented the page not found the error I was getting was "No routes matched location "/"". My index.js has the BrowserRouter wrapping my

This is my app.js:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Routes, Route, Link, useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

import Notification from "./components/notification";
import LoginForm from "./components/loginForm";
import BlogPage from "./pages/blogs";

import { getBlogs } from "./store/blogReducer";
import { setUser } from "./store/userReducer";
import { setNotification } from './store/notifyReducer'
import { clearUser } from './store/userReducer'

const Menu = ({user}) => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    window.localStorage.removeItem("loggedBlogUser");
    dispatch(clearUser())
    dispatch(setNotification({message:'You have signed out', color:'green', time: 5}))
    navigate('/login')
  };

  if(location.pathname === '/login' || user === null) {
    return null
  }

  return (
    <nav>
        <Link to='/'>blogs</Link>
        <Link to='/users'>users</Link>
        <p>
          {user.name} logged in
          <button onClick={handleLogout}>
            logout
          </button>
        </p>
    </nav>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const user = useSelector(state => state.user)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedBlogUser')
    if(loggedUserJSON) {
      const user = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON)
      dispatch(getBlogs());
      dispatch(setUser(user))
    }
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <>
      <Menu user={user}/>
      <Routes>
        {!user ? (
        <Route path="/login" element={
          <>
            <Notification />
            <LoginForm />
          </>
        }/> ): (
            <Route path='/' element={<BlogPage />}>
              <Route path='/users' element={ <></> } />
            </Route>      
        )}
        <Route path="*" element={<div>Page not found</div>} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

My Login Form which uses the Navigate hook

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Login } from '../store/userReducer'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const LoginForm = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const handleLogin = async  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(Login({ username, password }))
    navigate('/')
  }

  return (
    <>
    <h1>Log into application</h1>
    <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
      <div>
        Username
        <input
          data-testid="username-input"
          type="text"
          value={username}
          name="Username"
          onChange={({ target }) => setUsername(target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        Password
        <input
          data-testid="password-input"
          type="password"
          value={password}
          name="Password"
          onChange={({ target }) => setPassword(target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <button data-testid="login-btn" type="submit">
        login
      </button>
    </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: I think issue is because of not-found route, by default React is moving to that because for other routes it is checking condition and next is not-found only.

What you can do is to move not found inside auth condition and check then.

Comment: You need not do conditional routing. Write both routes separately instead of using conditions.

Comment: Don't conditionally render routes. The issue here is that the state hasn't updated and rerendered the app prior to attempting to navigate to protected routes.

Answer (score 1):

The router cannot navigate correctly because you are conditionally rendering `Route` objects, so when you navigate to `/` the route is not in the page yet. Try to implement the `RequireAuth` pattern suggested on the [official docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth) ([Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/auth?file=src/App.tsx)).

You could create a RequireAuth component and rearrange your routes similarly to the following code.

**RequireAuth.js**

```js
function RequireAuth({ children }) {
  const user = useSelector(state => state.user)

  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
  }

  return children;
}
```

**App.js**

```js
function App() {
  // Component code

  return (
    <>
      <Menu user={user}/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={
          <>
            <Notification />
            <LoginForm />
          </>
        }/>
        <Route path="/" element={
          <RequireAuth>
            <Route index element={<BlogPage />}>
              <Route path="users" element={ <></> } />
            </Route>
          </RequireAuth>
        } />
        <Route path="*" element={<div>Page not found</div>} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```